# Failed to load manifest for workspace member error

Tags: pallet

> error: failed to load manifest for workspace member `/home/kaioh/dropbox-clone/node`
> Caused by:
> failed to load manifest for dependency `node-dropbox-runtime`
> Caused by:
> failed to load manifest for dependency `pallet-dropbox`
> Caused by:
> failed to read `/home/kaioh/dropbox-clone/pallets/template/Cargo.toml`
> Caused by:
> No such file or directory (os error 2)

I am trying to create a custom pallet in substrate for a dropbox clone. I forked the substrate node template and tried to edit it to suit what I want to do. I have tried checking through my `cargo.toml` files for node, runtime and also pallet template and can't find anything wrong. Can someone give me any tips on what to look for?

Comment: You havent configured your cargo.toml correctly that is the issue. Make sure the path is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this error means that something isn't formatted correctly in the cargo.toml file I think, or you have some dependency listed that doesn't exist or you gave the wrong folder path to it. Also related to this stuff, you should make sure the version of polkadot you are using is the same for everything. Don't just look in the file, search your whole project to see if you missed updating a dependency to the same version as everything else. If you miss even 1, it probably won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently in my runtime/Cargo.toml, I had not changed the path from the default which is "../pallets/template" to "../pallets/dropbox" and pallets/dropbox was declared twice under std features. Doing this fixed my issues.